# How to give proper width to a .png in email newsletter for outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, newsletter

I have developed a email newsletter. My developed email newsletter is working fine on all email clients except Outlook 2013 .

I am using an image in my email newsletter but it is not taking the table width which I have given, it is taking its own width i.e. 658px 
[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2hCw.jpg)

and the code for this table is

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="align:center;vertical-align:top;width:600px"> 
        <div style="width:600px;align:center">
          <img src="images/demo1.png" style="width:600px">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please provide suggestions on how to put the image inside the table

Answer (score 0):

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="align:center;vertical-align:top;width:600px"> 
<div style="width:300px;align:center">
<img src="images/demo1.png" width="300">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>`
```

Try this also

```
<img src="images/demo1.png"  style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" width="300">
```

Comment: no . still not getting the result . image is till taking its own width

Comment: i modified again give like that

Comment: replace the above mentioned img line onle and check

Comment: sorry? did'nt get that

Comment: image is taking its own width which is 658px but i wanr to give 600px width to image , which is not working . image extension is .png

Comment: sorry sir but your all suggestion are not working . image is still taking its own width rathter than table width

Answer (score 0):

try this, just set your width inside div and td tags and make image tag's width=100%.

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="align:center;vertical-align:top;width:600px"> 
<div style="width:300px;align:center">
<img src="images/demo1.png" style="width:100%;">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>`
```

Comment: change your table  like  <table  style="bgcolor:#ffffff; cellpadding:0; cellspacing:0; width:600px; align:center;"> ,let me know after that..

Comment: not working . except outlook 2013 my code for email newsletter is working fine on all email newsletter clients

Comment: make  background-repeat:no-repeat; and -webkit-background-size: cover;

Comment: no positive result . same issue . image is still taking its own width in outlook 2013